# Compare digits of numbers in R

Tags: r

**Hello everyone. Thanks in advance for any help** 
I want to compare and classify two columns of numbers based on their digits.
To make it clearer here is a small example:

| nr1 | nr2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1234 |
| 1234 | 1235 |
| 1234 | 1335 |
| 1234 | 2347 |
| 2876 | na |

I want to add a new column with these rules: 
When the numbers are the same it gets 4 
First 3 digits the same = 3
First 2 digits the same = 2
First digit the same =1 
Nothing the same = 0 
and if there is an na it should be na also in the comparison varible

I plan on doing that with an basic if else funktion

```
if (nr1 == nr 2) {
nr3 == "4"
} else if {
......
}
```

However 2 problems occured. I cant target a specific digit. I tried [C()] and transforming the number into a character. Also even if I just run the first statement without the else if I get logical(0). I red a few things about problems with == but since I am comparing numbers I cant figure out why it doesnt work.

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some simple maths:

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
  z <- abs(x - y)
  res <- 3 - floor(log10(z))
  res[is.infinite(res)] <- 4
  res
}

foo(df1$nr1, df1$nr2)
#[1]  4  3  1  0 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested `ifelse()` statements or something like `fcase()` from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

df$nr3 <- fcase(
  df$nr1 == df$nr2, '4',
  substr(df$nr1, 1L, 3L) == substr(df$nr2, 1L, 3L), '3',
  substr(df$nr1, 1L, 2L) == substr(df$nr2, 1L, 2L), '2',
  substr(df$nr1, 1L, 1L) == substr(df$nr2, 1L, 1L), '1',
  default = '0'
)


df
#    nr1  nr2 nr3
# 1 1234 1234   4
# 2 1234 1235   3
# 3 1234 1335   1
# 4 1234 2347   0
# 5 2876 <NA>   0
```

Reproducible data (please provide yourself next time):

```
df <- data.frame(
  nr1 = c(rep('1234', 4L), '2876'),
  nr2 = c('1234', '1235', '1335', '2347', NA_character_)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain the funktion some more. I dont understand the 1L, 3 L ...

Comment: @Ophelia 1L is more or less equivalent to 1. To see what `substr()` is doing try `substr(df$nr1, 1L, 3L)` and then maybe `substr(df$nr1, 2L, 3L)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way with `apply`.

```
eq <- function(x, y, which = 1:4){
  res <- sapply(which, function(n) n[substr(x, 1, n) == substr(y, 1, n)])
  max(0, unlist(res))
}

apply(df1, 1, function(x) eq(x[1], x[2]))
#[1]  4  3  1  0 NA
```

---

### Data in `dput` format

```
df1 <-
structure(list(nr1 = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 2876L), nr2 = c(1234L, 
1235L, 1335L, 2347L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```